# Remove GNU licence and 'no warranty' thing when logging into ssh

Tags: ssh

Whenever I login to my Pi via ssh I get this message:

```
pi@192.168.1.251's password: 
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

Is there a way how to disable that because it takes up half the screen when I login?

Thanks.

Comment: man motd (man is *nix help, motd is message of the day).

Comment: ctrl-L or clear will clear the screen. Here is what you want https://thomashunter.name/blog/a-better-debian-ssh-login-message/

Comment: I do ^L all the time. I wanted to remove the text so I didn't have to. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Joan notes, `motd` is the key. The [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/motd) has good information on how the motd file is generated at boot and how to modify it. Check out the **How to keep your /etc/motd from being overwritten** section to make permanent motd changes.

If you just want to disable it for your user, create a `.hushlogin` file in your home directory:

`touch ~/.hushlogin`

Comment: removed everything in the `motd` file and made the `hushlogin` file and that worked! Thanks. (Also I use vim not pico. :) )

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect the fact that debian regenerates the motd file. The wiki shows how to prevent this, but ~/.hushlogin is a lot easier! Oh, and I use vi as well. Just going along with the raspi flow.

Comment: I deleted everything in the motd file and it kepped the changes after reboot. Thanks for editing the answer (only rebooted to check that. :) )

Answer (score 2):

Remove /etc/motd and the message will no longer be displayed.

Comment: I'd use `sudo sh -c 'echo "" > /etc/motd'` to replace the file with an empty one.

Comment: What makes your answer different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @Ingo accepted says to modify, this says to delete? dunno.